# Verilog FSM being optimised away

Tags: verilog

New to Verilog, Basys3 board and Vivid 2021.2.

Trying to implement a typical stopwatch with Stop/Start and Lap/Reset buttons.

A divider produces 1kHz and 100Hz clock from the board clock, 100Hz is for button debounce (and seven segment display multiplexing, next todo), the 1kHz drives a 20 bit 5 x 4 bit BCD counter, the low 16 bits of which drive a latch to freeze the display, the latch drives the 16 on board LEDs.

I've test 'wired' this up and the modules perform as expected. It's only when I add the FSM I run into trouble.

The FSM is simple, the two buttons determine the state changes and the state sets three outputs to control the counter.

The state module as been through many versions, tried using buttons in the sensitivity list, tried with button edges and levels, tried *, tried blocking and non-blocking assignments, can't get it right. The current error is:

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (state/transfer_reg) is unused and will be removed from module stopwatch.

The error changes but it's always Synth 8-3332 removing something, even curr_state or next_state.

The RTL synthesis schematic shows exactly what I expect, later schematics show the two buttons, 16 LEDs and nothing in between.

I'm lost at this stage, have I missed something fundamental?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 
// Create Date: 02/02/2022 0800
//  
// Module Name: state
// Project Name: Stop Watch
// Target Devices: BASYS 3
// 
// state machine
//
//      inputs:
//              start-stop button via debounce (both edg and level are available)
//              lap-reset buttonvia debounce (both edg and level are available)
//
//      outputs:
//              control 4 x 4 bit BCD counters and output latch
//              clear state
//              enabvble couter to count
//.             transfer counter value to latch
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module state (
    input clk,
    input lap_reset,
    input start_stop,
    output reg clear,
    output reg enable,
    output reg transfer
    );

    // state encodings
    localparam  
        RESET_0     = 3'd0,
        STOPPED_1   = 3'd1,
        RUNNING_2   = 3'd2,
        PRELAP_3    = 3'd3,
        LAP_4       = 3'd4;
                
    // state reg
    reg[2:0] curr_state;
    reg[2:0] next_state;
    
    // setup
    initial
        begin
            curr_state <= RESET_0;
            next_state <= RESET_0;
            enable <= 0;
            clear <= 0;
            transfer <= 0;                    
        end

    // sync state transitons to clk
//    always @ (posedge clk)
//        begin
//            curr_state <= next_state;
//        end

    // state machine
     always @ (posedge clk)
        begin
            curr_state <= next_state;
            case (curr_state)
                RESET_0:
                    begin
                        // init, stop counter, clear counter
                        // transfer count to latch
                        enable <= 0;
                        clear <= 1;
                        transfer <= 1;
                        next_state <= STOPPED_1;
                    end
                STOPPED_1:
                    begin
                        // stop counter, clear counter
                        enable <= 0;
                        clear <= 0;
                        transfer <= 0;
                        if (start_stop)
                            next_state <= STOPPED_1;
                        else if (lap_reset)
                            next_state <= RESET_0;
                        else
                            next_state <= curr_state;
                    end
                RUNNING_2:
                    begin
                        // start or continue counting
                        // transfer count to latch
                        enable <= 1;
                        clear <= 0;
                        transfer <= 1;
                        if (start_stop)
                            next_state <= STOPPED_1;
                        else if (lap_reset)
                            next_state <= PRELAP_3;                  
                        else
                            next_state <= curr_state;
                    end                
                PRELAP_3:
                    begin
                        // start or continue counting
                        // don't update latch
                        enable <= 1;
                        clear <= 0;
                        transfer <= 0;
                        next_state <= LAP_4;
                    end                
                LAP_4:
                    begin
                        // continue counting
                        // transfer counter to latch
                        enable <= 1;
                        clear <= 0;
                        transfer <= 1;
                        if (start_stop)
                            next_state <= RUNNING_2;
                        else if (lap_reset)
                            next_state <= PRELAP_3;
                        else
                            next_state <= curr_state;
                    end
                default:
                    begin
                        enable <= 0;
                        clear <= 0;
                        transfer <= 0;                    
                        next_state <= RESET_0;
                    end                    
            endcase            
        end
endmodule
```

Comment: No simulation, this only my third attempt at Verilog, simulation is something I'm yet to tackle. I know the other modules work, I only posted the failing state module. I think I better have a go at simulation and test benches.

Comment: No reset signal handling. `initial` is for simulation and may be ignored in synthesis. Also, check what you do with the outputs, if they're ignored the whole module will be optimised out.

Answer (score 0):

Getting somewhere at last, thankyou all.

After correcting a logical error and a couple of constants 0'b0 which make little sense (the compiler didn't complain about them) and doing suggested fixes my stopwatch works.

The SM structure is the 3 blocks, sync transitions, next state 'gotos' and state actions. I started with the suggested always @ (*) but had to change to a posedge clk for it to work, not sure why.

Got rid of the inferred latches and now understand why they come about.

About generating a reset signal, I assume the Artix chip has one but it doesn't get a mention in the supplied xdc file, I was trying to simulate a reset held low (active) then going high a short time later, determined by a clock divider - which should have a reset... Also read Xilinx WP272 which tells a different story.

Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Just from [www.javatpoint.com/verilog-initial-block](http://www.javatpoint.com/verilog-initial-block):

> "An initial block is not synthesizable and cannot be converted into a
> hardware schematic with digital elements. The initial blocks do not
> have more purpose than to be used in simulations. These blocks are
> primarily used to initialize variables and drive design ports with
> specific values."

I am not sure now about the code for that FPGA, but in common ASICs I would remove the "initial" code section, which you use to implement the reset behaviour and add an actual reset section in the always@.

```
always@(posedge clk)
begin
  if (rst) begin
    // do the reset
    curr_state <= RESET_0;
    next_state <= RESET_0;
    enable <= 0;
    clear <= 0;
    transfer <= 0;
  end else begin
    // the rest
  end
end
```

EDITED:

Never leave a signal without a default value, as it will infer latches instead of flip-flops, which create problems when inferring sequential logic (of course latches are useful in some scenarios).

When one wants to build a finite state machine (FSM) there are two common approaches: Mealy and Moore. I will explain how the sequential logic should be implemented with a Moore FSM:

1. A synchronous always@ block to write the state: cur_state <= next state.
2. A combinational block to generate next_state value based on cur_state and inputs.
3. A combinational block to generate outputs based on the state.

   ```
    always@(posedge clk, rst)
    begin
      if (rst = '1') begin
        cur_state <= State_0;
      end else begin
        cur_state <= next_state;
      end
    end

    always_comb(cur_state, my_inputA)
    begin
      if (cur_state = State_0) begin
        if(my_inputA)
           next_state = State_1;
        else
           next_state = Stage_0;
      end else if (cur_state = State_1) begin
        next_state = State_2;
      end
    end

    always_comb(cur_state)
    begin
      if (cur_state = State_0) begin
        my_outputA = '1';
      end else if (cur_state = State_1) begin
        my_outputA = '0';
      end else if (cur_state = State_2) begin
        my_outputA = '1';
      end  
    end
   ```